# Find a cell and override the info

Tags: vba, excel, return, overriding

So I have a contract with information that I wanted to update in different columns...I need to look up this contract in a list of contracts and override specific information with the user inputs.

I tried the code below. I could locate the location of the contract on the list however override doesn't work. Can you please help?

```
Sub UpdateChargesMacro3()

    Dim contract As Double
    Dim BR_Reduction As Double
    Dim RIA_Reduction As Double
    Dim TR_Reduction As Double
    Dim PERA_Reduction As Double
    Dim TPA_Reduction As Double
    Dim JHHH_Reduction As Double
    Dim RowCount As Integer

    contract = Sheets("Input").Range("C29").Value
    JHHH_Reduction = Sheets("Input").Range("C36").Value

    Sheets("Final Summary").Select
    With ActiveSheet.Range("C:C")
        Set uRng = .Find(contract, , xlValues, xlWhole, , MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)

        If uRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox Prompt:="Contract not found!", Buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="OK"
        End If
        Exit Sub

        If Not uRng Is Nothing Then
            uRng.Activate
            RowCount = ActiveCell.Row
            Sheets("Final Summary").Range("DJ" & RowCount).value = JHHH_Reduction

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The "override" tag means "Method overriding, in object oriented programming, is a language feature that allows a subclass or child class to provide a specific implementation of a method that is already provided by one of its superclasses or parent classes." The "return" tag refers to a Return instruction. Is uRng Nothing or Not Nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If uRng Is Nothing Then
MsgBox Prompt:="Contract not found!", Buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="OK"
End If
Exit Sub
```

Always exits the macro,

move exit inside the if statement

```
If uRng Is Nothing Then
MsgBox Prompt:="Contract not found!", Buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="OK"
Exit Sub
End If
```